# One formula of the Serret Frenet

Tags: differential-geometry

I am studying differential geometry's elements and here is one of the formulas' derivation in the book i cannot quite understand.

> **Torsion**: $\vec{b}=\frac{d\vec{b}}{ds}$. So differentiating $\vec{b}=\vec{t}×\vec{n}$ we have $\frac{d\vec{b}}{ds}=\frac{d\vec{t}}{ds}×\vec{n}+\vec{t}×\frac{d\vec{n}}{ds}=\vec{t}×\frac{d\vec{n}}{ds}$, hence $\frac{d\vec{b}}{ds} \perp \vec{t}$, but it is also perpendicular to $\vec{b}$, and hence is parallel to $n$. Hence, we can write $$\frac{d\vec{n}}{ds}=-\tau\vec{n}$$

I cannot quite understand why the negative sign is present. It is perpendicular to $\vec{b}$, and parallel to $\vec{n}$, so it could have been in the direction of $\vec{n}$. Why is it in the opposite direction?

Comment: Frankly, I think it's just convention.

Comment: Is the torsion always negative?? I still now do not have any intuitive idea of torsion.

Comment: Are you sure you got the letters in your blockquote right? The equations $b=db/ds$ and $dn/ds=-\tau n$ can't be right. Each of $t,n,b$ should be perpendicular to their derivatives.

Comment: Whether $d\vec b/ds = +\tau\vec n$ or $d\vec b/ds = -\tau\vec n$ is a matter of convention. DoCarmo, in particular, uses a $+$ sign there, whereas most differential geometry authors use a $-$ sign. But what you've written is *full* of typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the negative sign present in the equation $db/ds=-\tau n$? The torsion $\tau$ measures how much $b$ (or really, the whole $nb$-plane) is rotating around $t$ as the curve is traversed. Using this convention (where negative sign is present in the equation), positive $\tau$ means it's rotating according to the right-hand-rule (with $t$ as your thumb), and is negative otherwise. If the negative sign were not present in the equation, this interpretation of $\tau$'s sign would be reversed.